# Jquery on.mouseenter and on.click same behavior bug on mobile

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a floating action button (FAB)...
On desktop, when i'm hovering the FAB, it's opening normally...
But... on mobile device, I need to click twice to get opened...

On mobile, I've seen that it's just like mouseenter was behaving same way as a click when i click the first time and only the first click then behave as a normal click... thus, i need to click 2 times instead of only once! I was thinking mouseenter and mouseleave would not work on mobile, only on desktop, that's not the case... so I don't really know what to do to open my FAB on hovering on desktop and on clicking only 1 time on mobile...

Any idea? 
Thanks much for your help!

```
  <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 35px; right: 24px;">
    <a class="btn-floating">
      <i>FAB</i>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="btn-floating">Action 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn-floating">Action 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn-floating">Action 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
(function ($) {
  var _this = this;

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.fixed-action-btn', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      openFABMenu($this);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.fixed-action-btn', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      closeFABMenu($this);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.fixed-action-btn', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      toggleFABMenu($('.fixed-action-btn'));
      return false;
    });
  });

  function openFABMenu(btn) {
    var fab = btn;

    if (!fab.hasClass('active')) {
      fab.addClass('active');
      var btnList = document.querySelectorAll('ul .btn-floating');
      btnList.forEach(function (el) {
        el.classList.add('shown');
      });
    }
  };

  function closeFABMenu(btn) {
    var fab = btn;
    fab.removeClass('active');
    var btnList = document.querySelectorAll('ul .btn-floating');
    btnList.forEach(function (el) {
      el.classList.remove('shown');
    });
  };

  function toggleFABMenu(btn) {
    var elem = btn;

    if (elem.hasClass('active')) {
      closeFABMenu(elem);
    } else {
      openFABMenu(elem);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

mouseenter doesn't work in mobile.
probably you should always show your fabMenu in mobile if it's okay.